# Rails ActiveRecord: Counting associations of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to write an ActiveRecord find query with no success.  Please help!

This feature of my project is kind of a blog with Digg-like features: each registered user can add a star to the blog post itself or any of its replies.

So here are the relevant model classes:

- BlogPost (has_many Replies)
- Reply (belongs_to Blog Post)
- Starring (this represents the action of one users starring one BlogPost or Reply; it has a polymorphic interface to BlogPost and Reply, referring to them internally as :starrables, replete with :starrable_id and :starrable_type fields)

So, what I am trying to do is write a method in blog_post.rb that will return the total number of starrings for the BlogPost object as well as all of its Reply classes.  That is, if a blog post has 10 stars, and it has two replies which each have 5 stars, it should return 20.

How do I write this query without making a jillion database transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing it with SQL.  You can do it several ways.  Are you using MYSQL?  If you want to do with with 2 queries and then add the numbers together you can do something like this in SQL:

`select count(starrings.id) from starrings where starrable_type='BlogPost' and starrable_id=#{blogpost.id}`

and

`select count(starrings.id) from starrings  join replies on starrings.starrable_type='Reply' and starrable_id=replies.id and replies.blog_post_id=#{blogpost.id}`

Note: I didn't test this SQL and may have misspelled something or made a typo.

You can run SQL counts with 'Starring.count_by_sql(your sql here)' then add the 2 numbers together.  You can probably get this down to 1 SQL statement with a union, but I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a polymorphic method `stars` on both the BlogPost and Reply that returns the `Starring` objects for each (you may not, but it makes sense to me that you should) then in blog_post.rb you can do:

```
def total_number_of_stars
  stars.size + replies.inject(0) { |s,v| s.stars.size += v.stars.size }
end
```

Admittedly this will do quite a few queries behind the scenes, but that's kind of how Rails works. If it does not perform well enough you can use find_by_sql with bespoke SQL.

Comment: I'm basically doing this now, but it's scaling terribly.  Assuming that there's a way to do this in one or two queries, I'd prefer to let the database do the heavy lifting.

Thanks though!